# spring.config.import is not working in spring application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
spring.config.import=file:/testFolder/test.properties

provided above property in application.properties and test.properties file present in required folder on server . baseurl property provided in test.properties and I am using it in application.properties using ${baseurl} ,

getting below exception 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'baseurl'
```

spring.config.import=file:/testFolder/test.properties

provided above property in application.properties and test.properties file present in required folder on server . baseurl property provided in test.properties and I am using it in application.properties using ${baseurl} ,

getting below exception
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'baseurl'

Comment: Can you format the question properly to begin with?